# HTMl Form values not store in its Database Properly

Tags: database, html, forms

When i select a value and then type a name in the text field and then press submit button, I need the data to go to the database.

[image]
Here is the code sample.

```
`<label>Name with Initials</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <select id="name_with_initials">
          <option selected="selected" value="mr">Mr.</option>
          <option value="mrs">Mrs.</option>
          <option value="miss">Miss.</option>
        </select>
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="name_with_initials" class="form-control" placeholder="Name with Initials">
    </div>`
```

if I use this, whatever the selected value not going to go the database, only typed name will go there.

Comment: post your database handling code .

Comment: @BhuneshSatpada Database Handling code means?

Comment: How are you storing data in database?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide name attribute to your titles. now title will also insert in to database.

```
<label>Name with Initials</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <select name="titles" id="name_with_initials">
          <option selected="selected" value="mr">Mr.</option>
          <option value="mrs">Mrs.</option>
          <option value="miss">Miss.</option>
        </select>
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="name_with_initials" class="form-control" placeholder="Name with Initials">
    </div>`
```

PHP

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
$name=$_POST['name_with_initials'];
```

Comment: So that do i have to save these data into two separate data attributes in a database?

Comment: yes if you want to, or if you want to save it in same column you have to merge both values before insert in database, like $fullname=$title." ".$name.

Comment: Bro do you know how to concat these two using laravel?

Comment: $name = Input::get('name_with_initials'); $title = Input::get('title'); now concatenate both $fullname=$name." ".$title;